# How do you properly redirect from an HTTPS page?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

Assume I have an SSL connection to a web site from a browser.
From the page I press a button and I am in another part of the site (different page). Under what circumstances would the connection be re-negotiated?
On servler redirect? Forward? What flow?
And what is the correct flow in this case? Note that all site is `HTTPS`. I.e. there are not plain `HTTP` areas or external links (adds etc).
Container would be tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

The SSL/TLS connection would typically be re-negotiated if the server requests it for client-certificate authentication (this is done by disabling client auth on the connector, but asking for `CLIENT-CERT` authentication within a webapp's `web.xml`).

Otherwise, the HTTP requests/responses are exchanged as part of the normal pool of concurrent TCP connections made by the browser (this has more to do with HTTP connection re-use than with SSL/TLS), with its usual timeout settings (not specific to SSL/TLS). Modern browsers should be able to re-use SSL/TLS sessions to avoid having to do a full SSL/TLS handshake for each. There is a timeout for SSL/TLS sessions too, but it's usually long enough; re-establishing a new connection will be done transparently by the browser anyway.

There are also [various mechanisms to reduce the overhead due to SSL/TLS handshakes](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html) (with support depending on the browser), although [False Start doesn't seem to be a success](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/04/11/falsestart.html).

Comment: But is a `Forward` the same as a `Redirect`?Perhaps a `Redirect` (302 I believe?) is an indication to the browser to reconnect to new location?Otherwise how can the behavior I describe and I see is explained?

Comment: A forward is done internally by the servlet, it's more about convenience for internal dispatch). A redirect makes the browser perform a new HTTP request, which doesn't necessarily mean a new connection.

Comment: But I am observing a new connection.Why does the browser do that?

Comment: How are you observing that new connection? (A forward won't lead to a new connection anyway, unless what it forwards to does.)

Comment: I see that by pressing a button I see **again** the "familiar" page to accept the server's untrusted certificate.I have already specified to ignore and I believe this page would be re-displayed only on a new SSL handshake. Right?

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to connect to a different host name the second time (with your redirect)?

Comment: Yes.It is in the same host name but different path!How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

When you click that button on a web page the connection is established (i.e. a GET or POST to the server). HTTP 1.1. keeps that connection open for the entire request to get all the resources such as the HTML of the web page and subsequent images, CSS, JS, etc. If you wanted to keep the connection open between user-initiated requests, you could look into [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). There is some controversy around if it should be used for https (or even http however).

Despite keep-alive settings, your browser may or may not attempt to keep the connection open for a period of time anyway in case you click something else in say a 60 second window. The above link gives some more detail on this.

Servlet redirects or forwards should have no implications or reasons to renegotiate the connection. It would use the same one as it created when the user clicked the button.

Comment: But is a Forward the same as a redirect?Perhaps a redirect always initiates a new connection?

Comment: Not exactly. A forward is done on the server side, a redirect is a 2-step process where it tells the browser where to go, then the browser resubmits the query to the new address. I still doubt that even a redirect initiates a new connection. Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The more I think about it, it must be the same connection. With typical "redirect", the server responds with a 301 status code and the URL to go to. The browser simply makes that call to the new URL. It's still the same conversation with the server so must be the same connection.

Comment: But I am observing a renegotiation.Why would that happen?

Comment: Is it possible your button click is actually redirecting to a different server? That's the only way I can think of that you would be asked to accept the [unsigned] certificate again. That acceptance should persist throughout the users session.